# How many genes are needed for a living organism?

Tags: genetics, evolution, dna, amino-acids, life

I am interested in this question as I'm doing research into early life on earth which is believed to have been single-celled. Therefore, by extension, it seems only logical that the first life would be as genetically simple as is possible, therefore I present the above question.

How many genes / pairs of AA would be the bare minimum for something to be considered alive and function as an organism.

Comment: Hi there. You're right the question is the same but the answer given doesn't link any studies and i think it's also possible that the date is outdated.

Comment: Related wikipedia articles: [Constitutive gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Constitutive_gene&redirect=no), [Housekeeping gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housekeeping_gene) , [Minimal Genome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_genome) and [repressible system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_of_gene_expression#Inducible_vs._repressible_systems). Though they are not same thing, but they are related concepts.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56363/6307