# What would it take to create life?

Tags: life, artificial-life

Assume we know the right DNA sequence of Mycoplasma Genitalium (MG) and we would like to create Life from scratch. 
Also assume that matter has been created and we have the knowledge base as today.

How could we practically or theoretically take such a sequence and create a new MG?

I saw this in case you want to read more:

https://www.quantamagazine.org/first-support-for-a-physics-theory-of-life-20170726/

Comment: What do you mean by "from scratch"?

Comment: @canadianer given the chemical elements we know today.

Comment: You mean chemically synthesize the genome and every other component of the cell?

Comment: @canadianer yes, how to create life? Given the Big Bang occurred.

Comment: The first step would be a definition of life.

Comment: @John how a cell was created at the Big Bang?

Comment: It wasn't, there is about 10 billion years between the big bang and the first life. the earth is only about 4.5 billion years old.

Comment: I wouldn't say that recreating an organism from a known genome is creating life from scratch.  That would require designing a genome for an organism that doesn't exist in nature.

Comment: @jamesqf but except that one condition (i.e. taking DNA sequence information only, of another organism), could we synthesize life from cell-free chemical reagents?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused At a minimum you would need some transcription machinery, and probably translation as well (unless you are able to transcribe your translation machinery).

Comment: @Bryan Krause: I suppose you might boodstrap things by inserting your created genome into an existing cell, thus using its machinery to create the first new creature.  But I think we're quite a ways from even doing that.

Comment: @jamesqf People are doing that; see [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55914/is-designing-alien-life-still-just-science-fiction/56363#56363) and the references therein. If memory serves me right, that group is actually working with Mycoplasma genitalium.

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah having an entire functioning cell's machinery and just replacing the DNA is definitely the easiest way to go (and the approach people in the field are taking, like canadianer mentions), even if it might be difficult to use a different species' machinery. The problem with simplifying it more than that is even bacteria and archaea have evolved well past the likely initial stages of life back in the putative RNA world. Everything in a cell is highly interconnected functionally.

Comment: @canadianer: While that's certainly interesting, I'm not sure that it counts as creating life.  For an analogy, it'd be rather like making a hot rod by stripping all the unnecessary pieces off a car, as opposed to designing & building a car from scratch.

Comment: @BryanKrause Is there any instance/ report that human ever made a living cell from absolutely cell-free chemical reagents (even without a piece of macromolecule taken from living sources)?

Comment: I am really too interested to know, if (suppose) we are able to assemble atoms from nonliving matter with a hypothetical hand (comparable to laser trap), then would it be able to metabolize and grow just like living cell or it will left there like a dead cell.